# How do I transpose music chords using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, music-notation

I was wondering how would one create a javascript function for transposing music chords.

Since I don't expect everyone to be a musician here, I'll try to explain how it works in music theory. I hope I don't forget something. If yes, musicians, please, correct me.

1) The simple chords

The simple chords are almost as simple as an alphabet and it goes like this:

> C, C#, D, D#, E, F, F#, G, G#, A, A# B

From B it loops all over again to C. Therefore, If the original chord is `E` and we want to transpose +1, the resulting chord is `F`. If we transpose +4, the resulting chord is `G#`.

2) Expanded chords

They work almost like the simple chords, but contain a few more characters, which can safely be ignored when transposing. For example:

> Cmi, C#7, Dsus7, Emi, Fsus4, F#mi, G ...

So again, as with the simple chords, if we transpose `Dsus7` + 3 = `Fsus7`

3) Non-root bass tone

A problem arises when the bass plays a different tone than the chord root tone. This is marked by a slash after the chord and also needs to be transposed. Examples:

> C/G, Dmi/A, F#sus7/A#

As with examples 1 and 2, everything is the same, but the part after the slash needs transpose too, therefore:

`C/G` + 5 = `F/C`

`F#sus7/A#` + 1 = `Gsus7/B`

I think this should be all, unless I forgot something.

So basically, imagine you have a javascript variable called `chord` and the transpose value `transpose`. What code would transpose the chord?

Example:

```
var chord = 'F#sus7/C#';
var transpose = 3; // remember this value also may be negative, like "-4"
... code here ...
var result; // expected result = 'Asus7/E';
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about a little somethin' like this:

```
function transposeChord(chord, amount) {
  var scale = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"];
  return chord.replace(/[CDEFGAB]#?/g,
                       function(match) {
                         var i = (scale.indexOf(match) + amount) % scale.length;
                         return scale[ i < 0 ? i + scale.length : i ];
                       });
}

alert(transposeChord("Dm7/G", 2)); // gives "Em7/A"
alert(transposeChord("Fmaj9#11", -23)); // gives "F#maj9#11"
```

Note that I threw in the "F#maj9#11" example just to give you more to think about with regard to what makes up a valid chord name: you may find a "#" sharp symbol that doesn't follow a letter (in this case it belongs to the "11").

And, obviously, my function only understands sharps, not flats, and doesn't understand keys, so, e.g., `transposeChord("C/E", 1)` will give "C#/F" when it really should be "C#/E#".

Comment: Accepting this answer for providing the full solution, including the bass part.

Comment: If you feel like expanding the function, do it so that it also understand flats and keys and everything you consider necessary and I'm willing to reward you with a 400 reputation bounty! If you do so, please keep in mind that I need it in the Northern European, which goes like this: C C# D D# E F F# G G# A B H C ... it's in the table at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note

Comment: +1.  This handles the modulus better than mine, and the function allows you to be more general (even more than the two parts specified in the question).

Comment: I think a full implementation is way beyond what I have time for (even with the offer of 400 rep). When transposing a single chord you don't have enough information as to whether flats or sharps apply: you also need to know the key that the song will be in after it is transposed. (Though you could probably take a guess that _most_ of the time you want, e.g., Bb not A#.)

Answer (score 5):

Just to expand on nnnnnn's answer. We can take his code and add a little bit more code to actually make it work with flats.

```
transposeChord("F#sus7/A#", 1)
> "Gsus7/B"

transposeChord("Bb", 1)
> "B"

... works like a charm
```

```js
function transposeChord(chord, amount) {
    var scale = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"]
    var normalizeMap = {"Cb":"B", "Db":"C#", "Eb":"D#", "Fb":"E", "Gb":"F#", "Ab":"G#", "Bb":"A#",  "E#":"F", "B#":"C"}
    return chord.replace(/[CDEFGAB](b|#)?/g, function(match) {
        var i = (scale.indexOf((normalizeMap[match] ? normalizeMap[match] : match)) + amount) % scale.length;
        return scale[ i < 0 ? i + scale.length : i ];
    })
}
```

```html
<!-- Example Page -->
Chord:        <input id="chord" type="text" value="C#" style="width:70px"> 
transposed by <input id="amount" type="number" value="0" style="width:30px"> 
=             <input id="new-chord" type="text" style="width:70px">
              <button onclick="document.getElementById('new-chord').value = transposeChord(document.getElementById('chord').value,parseInt(document.getElementById('amount').value))">Calculate</button>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function transpose(chord, increment)
{
    var cycle = ["C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B"];
    var el = chord.charAt(0);
    if(chord.length > 1 && chord.charAt(1) == '#')
    {
        el += "#";   
    }
    var ind = cycle.indexOf(el);
    var newInd = (ind + increment + cycle.length) % cycle.length;
    var newChord = cycle[newInd];
    return newChord + chord.substring(el.length);
}
```

I'll let you figure out the bass part, since it's really just calling the function twice.

Also, you can add the code [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) before the function for old browsers that don't support `indexOf`.

I put a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QXHWD/4/) on jsFiddle.

EDIT: The issue was with negative modulus.  The above will work as long as long as the negative isn't more than the length (e.g. you can't transpose 100 steps down).

Comment: The -1 decrementing seems to cause problems, try going down multiple times here > http://inekafe.rimmer.sk/

Comment: Seems like it cannot transpose down from C to the end of the cycle, B. It returns undefined. ``C`` -1 returns ``undefined``

Comment: @RiMMER, try the modified version.

Comment: it seems to work now. So for the bass part, I just look for a slash using indexOf, then transpose the part, if found, right?

Comment: Thanks, I'll figure out the rest then, but maybe it should be contained here for the future visitors too. By the way - are you a musician? You seem to have understood the problem pretty easily.

Comment: Not anymore, but I played clarinet way back, and my family is pretty musical.  So I'm familiar with the basic scale.  You should ask a followup about the circle of fifths. :)  Also, feel free to post an addition to this answer with the `/` part.

Answer (score 1):

Define your keys with an object:

```
var keys = ["A", "A#", "B", "C", "C#", "D", "D#", "E", "F", "F#", "G", "G#"];
```

Parse your chord with a regular expression:

```
var matches = /([A-G]#?)([^\/]*)(?:\/([A-G]#?))?/.exec(chord);
var key = matches[1];
var descriptor = matches[2];
var bass = matches[3];
```

Do a little math to get the new key:

```
var newKey = keys[(keys.indexOf(key) + transpose) % keys.length];
var newBass = keys[(keys.indexOf(bass) + transpose) % keys.length];
```

Put it all back together again:

```
var newChord = newKey + descriptor;
if (newBass) {
    newChord += "/" + newBass;
}
return newChord;
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the expression: Invalid regular expression: /([A-G]#?)([^\/]*)(?:\/([A-G]#?)/: Unterminated group

Comment: I fixed it, but I'm unable to test it right now because I'm posting from my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I've thought about this a fair bit now, and I have a functional answer. It's in standard Western Scale tones (sorry Northern Europeans).

To truly transpose a chord you need 3 pieces of information: 1) the CHORD name, 2) the OLDKEY, and 3) the NEWKEY. It's not always enough to modulate by an AMOUNT (is UP-2 from the key of E an F# or a Gb?).

Basically you need to preserve two distances – the distance in pitch between the CHORD and the OLDKEY, and the distance in 'letters' between the CHORD and the OLDKEY – when mapping the CHORD to the NEWKEY.

```
function transposeChord(chord, oldKey, newKey) {}
```

To simplify(?) this, I've predefined every scale and every possible note (and some impossible ones) in relation to that scale root.

```
    var scales = {
    // scale_form = [1-7, #1-7, b1-7, *1-7, bb1-7]
    "CScale": ["C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "D#", "E#", "F#", "G#", "A#", "B#", "Cb", "Db", "Eb", "Fb", "Gb", "Ab", "Bb", "C*", "D*", "E*", "F*", "G*", "A*", "B*", "Cbb", "Dbb", "Ebb", "Fbb", "Gbb", "Abb", "Bbb"],
    "GScale": ["G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F#", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C#", "D#", "E#", "F*", "Gb", "Ab", "Bb", "Cb", "Db", "Eb", "F", "G*", "A*", "B*", "C*", "D*", "E*", "F#*", "Gbb", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cbb", "Dbb", "Ebb", "Fb"],
    "DScale": ["D", "E", "F#", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C*", "Db", "Eb", "F", "Gb", "Ab", "Bb", "C", "D*", "E*", "F#*", "G*", "A*", "B*", "C#*", "Dbb", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gbb", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cb"],
    "AScale": ["A", "B", "C#", "D", "E", "F#", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C*", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G*", "Ab", "Bb", "C", "Db", "Eb", "F", "G", "A*", "B*", "C#*", "D*", "E*", "F#*", "G#*", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cb", "Dbb", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gb"],
    "EScale": ["E", "F#", "G#", "A", "B", "C#", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G*", "A#", "B#", "C*", "D*", "Eb", "F", "G", "Ab", "Bb", "C", "D", "E*", "F#*", "G#*", "A*", "B*", "C#*", "D#*", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gb", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cb", "Db"],
    "BScale": ["B", "C#", "D#", "E", "F#", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C*", "D*", "E#", "F*", "G*", "A*", "Bb", "C", "D", "Eb", "F", "G", "A", "B*", "C#*", "D#*", "E*", "F#*", "G#*", "A#*", "Bbb", "Cb", "Db", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gb", "Ab"],
    "F#Scale": ["F#", "G#", "A#", "B", "C#", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G*", "A*", "B#", "C*", "D*", "E*", "F", "G", "A", "Bb", "C", "D", "E", "F#*", "G#*", "A#*", "B*", "C#*", "D#*", "E#*", "Fb", "Gb", "Ab", "Bbb", "Cb", "Db", "Eb"],
    "C#Scale": ["C#", "D#", "E#", "F#", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C*", "D*", "E*", "F*", "G*", "A*", "B*", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C#*", "D#*", "E#*", "F#*", "G#*", "A#*", "B#*", "Cb", "Db", "Eb", "Fb", "Gb", "Ab", "Bb"],
    "G#Scale": ["G#", "A#", "B#", "C#", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G*", "A*", "B*", "C*", "D*", "E*", "F#*", "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F#", "G#*", "A#*", "B#*", "C#*", "D#*", "E#*", "F**", "Gb", "Ab", "Bb", "Cb", "Db", "Eb", "F"],
    "D#Scale": ["D#", "E#", "F*", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C*", "D*", "E*", "F#*", "G*", "A*", "B*", "C#*", "D", "E", "F#", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "D#*", "E#*", "F**", "G#*", "A#*", "B#*", "C**", "Db", "Eb", "F", "Gb", "Ab", "Bb", "C"],
    "A#Scale": ["A#", "B#", "C*", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G*", "A*", "B*", "C#*", "D*", "E*", "F#*", "G#*", "A", "B", "C#", "D", "E", "F#", "G#", "A#*", "B#*", "C**", "D#*", "E#*", "F**", "G**", "Ab", "Bb", "C", "D#", "Eb", "F", "G"],
    // E#Scale:
    // B#Scale: 
    "FScale": ["F", "G", "A", "Bb", "C", "D", "E", "F#", "G#", "A#", "B", "C#", "D#", "E#", "Fb", "Gb", "Ab", "Bbb", "Cb", "Db", "Eb", "F*", "G*", "A*", "B#", "C*", "D*", "E*", "Fbb", "Gbb", "Abb", "Bbbb", "Cbb", ,"Dbb", ,"Ebb"],
    "BbScale": ["Bb", "C", "D", "Eb", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "D#", "E", "F#", "G#", "A#", "Bbb", "Cb", "Db", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gb", "Ab", "B#", "C*", "D*", "E#", "F*", "G*", "A*", "Bbbb", "Cbb", "Dbb", "Ebbb", "Fbb", "Gbb", "Abb"],
    "EbScale": ["Eb", "F", "G", "Ab", "Bb", "C", "D", "E", "F#", "G#", "A", "B", "C#", "D#", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gb", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cb", "Db", "E#", "F*", "G*", "A#", "B#", "C*", "D*", "Ebbb", "Fbb", "Gbb", "Abbb", "Bbbb", "Cbb", "Dbb"],
    "AbScale": ["Ab", "Bb", "C", "Db", "Eb", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "D", "E", "F#", "G#", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cb", "Dbb", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gb", "A#", "B#", "C*", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G*", "Abbb", "Bbbb", "Cbb", "Dbbb", "Ebbb", "Fbb", "Gbb"],
    "DbScale": ["Db", "Eb", "F", "Gb", "Ab", "Bb", "C", "D", "E", "F#", "G", "A", "B", "C#", "Dbb", "Ebb", "Fb", "Gbb", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cb", "D#", "E#", "F*", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C*", "Dbbb", "Ebbb", "Fbb", "Gbbb", "Abbb", "Bbbb", "Cbb"],
    "GbScale": ["Gb", "Ab", "Bb", "Cb", "Db", "Eb", "F", "G", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F#", "Gbb", "Abb", "Bbb", "Cbb", "Dbb", "Ebb", "Fb", "G#", "A#", "B#", "C#", "D#", "E#", "F*", "Gbbb", "Abbb", "Bbbb", "Cbbb", "Dbbb", "Ebbb", "Fbb"]
    // CbScale:
    // FbScale:
    // BbbFlatScale:
    //  ...
    }
```

Then you assign your scales based on the OLDKEY and NEWKEY:

```
var oldKeyScale = scales[key + "Scale"]
var newKeyScale = scales[newKey + "Scale"]
```

Finally, some regex to find and replace all those chord-roots/flats/sharps/doubleflats/etc with their corresponding position in the NEWKEY scale.

```
var transposedChord
transposedChord = chord.replace(/(([CDEFGAB]#\*)|([CDEFGAB]#)|([CDEFGAB]b+)|([CDEFGAB]\**))/g, function(match) {
    var i = oldKeyScale.indexOf(match)
    return newKeyScale[i]
})
return transposedChord
```

There's definitely a better, more 'think-like-a-computer' way to do this, but this will take

```
transposeChord("Am7/G", "C", "A#")
```

and return

```
"F*m7/E#"
```

Comment: Why is all this specificity necessary? Because the progression **A | E | F#m | D** when taken up a halfstep to the key of A# (because some people are masochists) _should_  come out to **A# | E# | F*m | D** and any implementation that doesn't deal with double-sharps will give you **Gm** instead.

Comment: In your comment you say that D would still be D after transposition. (Typo?)

Comment: Very much a typo, good catch. Should be D# (and is when transposed via above method).

Comment: You could avoid the switch statements if you stored the scale arrays as properties of an object with the key names ("C#", etc.) as property names.

Comment: Haha had that exact thought yesterday. Initially i was getting some weird behavior with naming variables with a '#', but object keys should be fine. Worstcase i sub 'sharp' for '#'. Goodcall.

Answer (score 1):

All of these solutions are lacking the fact that after transposing a note, it needs to be converted to a sharp or flat depending on the key or chord.

So the API must be:

```
transpose(note, semitones, useSharps)
```

Here is my implementation.  It also handles multiple # and b modifiers.

```
function transposeNote(note, semitones, useSharps) {
  // parse root followed by modifiers (# and b)
  const rx = /^([a-gA-G])([#b]*)$/;
  const m = rx.exec(note);
  if (!m) {
    return null;
  }
  // convert note from 0 to 11 based off of A
  let root;
  switch (m[1].toUpperCase()) {
    case "A":
      root = 0;
      break;
    case "B":
      root = 2;
      break;
    case "C":
      root = 3;
      break;
    case "D":
      root = 5;
      break;
    case "E":
      root = 7;
      break;
    case "F":
      root = 8;
      break;
    case "G":
      root = 10;
      break;
  }
  // modify root
  let mods = m[2];
  if (mods) {
    for (var i = 0; i < mods.length; i++) {
      if (mods.charAt(i) === "#") {
        root++;
      } else {
        root--;
      }
    }
  }
  // transpose note
  root = (root + semitones) % 12;

  if (root < 0) {
    root += 12
  }

  // convert back to a note
  const sharps = [
    "A",
    "A#",
    "B",
    "C",
    "C#",
    "D",
    "D#",
    "E",
    "F",
    "F#",
    "G",
    "G#"
  ];
  const flats = [
    "A",
    "Bb",
    "B",
    "C",
    "Db",
    "D",
    "Eb",
    "E",
    "F",
    "Gb",
    "G",
    "Ab"
  ];
  const transposedNote = useSharps ? sharps[root] : flats[root];
  return transposedNote;
}

function transposeChord(chord, semitones, useSharps) {
  const rx = /^([a-gA-G][#b]*)\s*([^\/]*)(\/[a-gA-G][#b]*)?$/;
  const m = rx.exec(chord);
  if (!m) {
    return null;
  }
  const root = transposeNote(m[1], semitones, useSharps);
  const quality = m[2] || "";
  let bass = m[3] || "";
  if (bass.length > 0) {
    bass = "/" + transposeNote(bass.substring(1), semitones, useSharps);
  }
  return root + quality + bass;
}
```

Use it like this

```
console.log(transposeChord("Cmin7/Eb", 3, false));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function transposechord(chord, amount){
   var scale = ["C","Cb","C#","D","Db","D#","E","Eb","E#","F","Fb","F#","G","Gb","G#",
         "A","Ab","A#","B","Bb","B#"];
   var transp = ["Cb","C","C#","Bb","Cb","C","C","C#","D","Db","D","D#","C","Db","D",
                 "D","D#","E","Eb","E","F","D","Eb","E", "E","E#","F#", "E","F","F#",
                 "Eb","Fb","F","F","F#","G","Gb","G","G#","F","Gb","G", "G","G#","A", 
                 "Ab","A","A#","G","Ab","A","A","A#","B","Bb","B","C","A","Bb","B", 
                 "B","B#","C#"];
   var subst = chord.match(/[^b#][#b]?/g);
   for(var ax in subst){
      if(scale.indexOf(subst[ax])!==-1){
         if(amount>0){
            for(ix=0;ix<amount;ix++){
                var pos = scale.indexOf(subst[ax]);
                var transpos = 3*pos-2+3;
                subst[ax] = transp[transpos+1];
            }
         }
         if(amount<0){
            for(ix=0;ix>amount;ix--){
                var pos = scale.indexOf(subst[ax]);
                var transpos = 3*pos-2+3;
                subst[ax] = transp[transpos-1];
                }
            }
       } 
   }
   chord=subst.join("");
}
```

chord = C/B, amount = 1:
C#/C 
or 
chord = Gm7, amount 2:
Am7

Comment: It would be nice to add some context and explanation to your code. Just posting a piece of code is not always helpful.

Comment: If you took C/B up one semitone it would "normally"  be either C#/B# or Db/C (depending on what key the song is in). Not that my answer does that properly either.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a transpose for chord lines in a guitar/ukulele song sheet and came up with the following functions which maintain spacing if space allows, and re-uses 7/dim/sus4 type information:

```
    function transposeChord( chord, amount ) {
        const sharpnotes = ["A","A#","B","C","C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G","G#"];
        const flatnotes  = ["A","Bb","B","C","Db","D","Eb","E","F","Gb","G","Ab"];
        let rootChord = chord[0];
        if(chord[1] === '#' || chord[1] == 'b') {
            rootChord += chord[1];
        }
        amount = (amount % sharpnotes.length) || 1;
        if(amount < 0) { amount += sharpnotes.length; }
        for(let note=0; note < sharpnotes.length; ++note) {
            if(rootChord === sharpnotes[note]) {
                return( (sharpnotes[(note + amount) % sharpnotes.length]) + chord.substr(rootChord.length) );
            }
            if(rootChord === flatnotes[note]) {
                return( (flatnotes[(note + amount) % flatnotes.length]) + chord.substr(rootChord.length) );
            }
        }
        return ('???');
    }

    function transposeChordLine( line, amount ) {
        amount = amount || 1;
        let count = 0;
        let newLine = '';

        while(count < line.length) {
            if(line[count] >= 'A' && line[count] <= 'G') {
                let chord = line[count++];
                while (count < line.length && line[count] !== ' ' && (line[count] < 'A' || line[count] > 'G')) {
                    chord += line[count++];
                }
                let newChord = transposeChord(chord, amount);
                if(newChord.length < chord.length) {    // pad if shorter
                    newChord += " ";
                }
                if(newChord.length > chord.length && count < line.length && (line[count] < 'A' || line[count] > 'G')) { // trim if there's space
                    count++;
                }
                newLine += newChord;
            } else {
                newLine += line[count++];
            }
        }
        return(newLine);
    }
```

so (for example)

```
transposeChordLine("     C          D7    Dm7    Gb7 ", 4)
```

outputs

```
"     E          F#7   F#m7   Bb7 "
```

Flats and sharps are presumed to remain b/# when transposed if appropriate.